# Getting rid of QMAKE-generated makefile's output spam

Tags: makefile, qmake

If I would write makefile by hand , I can do something like this

```
 CXX = @g++

 %.o: %.cpp makefile
        @echo Compiling $< ...
        $(CXX) -c $(FLAGS) $<
```

This would hide the executed command (thanks to @) but leaves all diagnostic and compiler's output. It would remove huge lists of parameters out of output log, but also would leave a comprehensive message.

I'm unable to reproduce this behaviour with Qmake, because all I can supply is a variable named QMAKE_CXX, content of which it would paste as a compiler, no way to insert a line break to my knowledge. Using these commands results in output like this

Compiling main.cpp...; @g++ -c -o main.o  main.cpp

Can I organize output similar to manual compiler while using only QMAKE project file?

Comment: Does `CONFIG += silent` looks okay?

Comment: @Matt Didn't knew of it it's not in written documentation. (and online one is blocked) Oh, so they use && and one @? I didn't thought of that. Almost does. It seem to have been bugged with UIC in version we use. Also sometimes need more than just echo. PS. Apparently QMAKE 4.x - 5.x unable to use QMAKE_UIC

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this:

```
 QMAKE_CXX = @echo "Message" && $$QMAKE_CXX
```

QMAKE apparently got undocumented QMAKE_UIC and QMAKE_MOC, with former being broken in some versions. Also an undocumented `CONFIG += silent` which replaces command lines with similar messages and uses same principle.